# C# mixing the streams

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, byte

Faced with the problem: write the same array of bytes every 40 milliseconds to a stream. Reads this thread in an infinite loop. But the byte array comes completely wrong. Could this be the mixing streams, anyone faced this problem?

Write array of bytes:

```
public void HandleCommunication()
    {
        var dataBytes = new List<byte>();

        foreach (double value in _values)
        {
            dataBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
        }

        _client.GetStream().Write(dataBytes.ToArray(), 0, dataBytes.Count);
        _client.GetStream().Flush();
    }
```

And Read array of bytes: after two times array of bytes comes wrong.

```
public void GetData()
    {
        TcpClient client = _server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        while (true)
        {
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            Values = new double[2 * 16 * 1024];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Values.Length * sizeof(double)];

            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Flush();               
        }
```

**And when I read data every 250 miliseconds array of bytes comes correctly!**

**Okay, more details:**
I have a text file with numbers.I read it and sends:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double[] values;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(40);
    Client _client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 55443);


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OpenSrcFile();

        timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }


    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _client.SendValues(values);
    }


    public void OpenSrcFile()
    {
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt").ToList();
        string r = lines[0];
        int sizeX = int.Parse(lines[1]);
        lines.RemoveRange(0, 2);
        values = GetValues(lines.ToArray());
    }
```

}

Client code:

```
class Client
{ 
    private TcpClient _client;
    private Stream _stream;
    private double[] _values;


    public Client(String ipAddress, int portNum)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient() { SendBufferSize = 2 * 16 * 1024 * sizeof(double) };
        _client.Connect(ipAddress, portNum);
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
    }


    public void SendValues(double[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
        HandleCommunication();
    }


    public void HandleCommunication()
    {

        _isConnected = true;

        var dataBytes = new List<byte>();

        foreach (double value in _values)
        {
            dataBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
        }

        NetworkStream newStream = _client.GetStream();
        _client.GetStream().Write(dataBytes.ToArray(), 0, dataBytes.Count);
        _client.GetStream().Flush();

    }

}
```

The server then receives this byte array, but I send every time the same array. But acceptance of the byte array is different after two iterations!
Server code:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener _server;


    public Server(int port)
    {
        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
        _server.Start();
    }

    public double[] Values { get; private set; }

    public delegate void DataUpdatedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public event DataUpdatedEventHandler DataUpdated;

    protected virtual void OnDataUpdated()
    {
        DataUpdatedEventHandler handler = DataUpdated;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }


    public void GetData()
    {


        // wait for client connection

        TcpClient client = _server.AcceptTcpClient();

        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");



        while (true)
        {
            var stream = client.GetStream();

                Values = new double[2 * 16 * 1024];
                byte[] buffer = new byte[Values.Length * sizeof(double)];



                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //wrong array of bytes!



                for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
                {
                    Values[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, i * sizeof(double));
                }



                OnDataUpdated();

        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand what is it...

Comment: Check the return values of `Write()` and `Read()`.

Comment: Why do you `Flush()` when reading?

Comment: This question is too vague. Please be specific about what's wrong, stating clearly what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Also, you should post a more complete code example, showing exactly the data you are sending. All that said, one major problem with your code is that you ignore the return value of `stream.Read()`, so if you initially receive only part of the data sent, you'll never find out.

Comment: describe all the details

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MS article on TcpClient class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As you can see, streams in .Net can have variable length on bytes.
You should get your data with:

```
  Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes);
```